# How to delete something from a list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a Suduoku game. Every time I use a number, I need to delete it from the list.

I have already tried `.pop[1]`, but it did nothing when the number was one.

```
import random

rownum1 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
print(random.choice(rownum1))

if random.choice(rownum1) == "1":
    del rownum1[0]
    print(rownum1)
```

If one is randomly selected I expect the output to be:

```
["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
```

But nothing is happening when one is randomly chose.

Comment: You are choosing a random string, printing it, then choosing **another** string and compare it to "1"!

Comment: random.choice(rownum1) produces a single value based on random, so  selecting the correct number (e.g., 1) with random is hard.

Comment: I put random.choice(rownum1) in a while loop for 3 rounds and this was the output: pass one: 4, 8, 2, 9, 8, 1, 4, 4, 1 -- pass two: 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 2, 1, 2, 7 -- pass three: 6, 6, 4, 9, 9, 2, 4, 9, 7 -- your code requires some reengineering to use random.

Comment: P.S.  Why are you using random to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

You are choosing a random string, printing it, then choosing **another** string and compare it to "1"!

Each time you call `random.choice(rownum1)`, you will get a new random string. The correct way to do what you want is to store the random string in a variable:

```
import random

rownum1 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
num = random.choice(rownum1) # <- store the value in a variable for later reuse
print(num)

if num == "1":
    del rownum1[0]
    print(rownum1)
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem with doing .pop[1] on your particular list is that the items in your list are strings, whereas 1 is an integer. Thus, you must do .pop("1") to remove the "1" from your list.

Comment: `list.pop()` (note the parantheses) takes as input an index to delete, it is not like `list.remove()`

Comment: I tried this but i get the error: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable